# pages loading twice in Jquery Mobile website

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

As my heading says the pages in my Jquery Mobile Web App loads twice  . I tried most of Stack answers provided on stack.

1. I have called the `Jquery 1.11.0` first then the css for the web site and then in the end `jquery mobile js`.
2. I changed all the `document.ready()` to `$( '#outerPage' ).on( 'pageinit',function(event){`
3. **HTML**

Still the pages are loading twice any more suggestion are appreciated .

Thanks

Comment: Is there another reference to jquery?

Comment: @LiamHT I also fixed the structure liek this `<body>
<div data-role="page">
 <!-- Content -->
</div>
</body>`

Comment: @LiamHT no I dont think so do you wanna have a look on the source code ?

Comment: sure, show it in your question

Comment: @LiamHT   oh its a big file bro it would not be possible to show in the question

Comment: I just need to see the html bit where you declare your scripts